# How to stop playing MediaPlayer when app is closed?

Tags: android, media-player

I have a song playing in my app, but it keeps going after I press the home button. I can't put this:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    ourSurfaceView.pause();
    if (ourSong.isPlaying()) {
        ourSong.pause();

    }
    super.onPause();
}
```

Because whenever I create a new Activity I finish() the last one.

Is there a certain method that can tell if the app is closed? How should I go about fixing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use method
`onWindowFocusChanged(boolean)`

as like

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus){

    if(hasFocus){

        if (!ourSong.isPlaying()) {
            ourSong.start();
        }

    }else{

        if (ourSong.isPlaying()) {
            ourSong.pause();
        }
    }
}
```

you can read more [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onWindowFocusChanged(boolean))